# Display array values before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi-step form and i wanted to display the array values on the last step before submitting.

I have no problem displaying form values before submit but i cant get it with arrays.

Here's my approach for input values:

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="Firstname" id="Firstname">
<span id="firstname_display"></span>
</form>

$("#Firstname").keyup(function(){
    $('#firstname_display').html($('#test').serialize());
});
```

My array:

```
 <td><input type="text" name="items[]"></td>
 <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
   <input type="button" id="addmore" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
 </td>
```

Comment: You're missing the `"` at the end of `type="text`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: i shorten my code before posting it on here, theres no need for all the class and style info.